# How to use an instance of an deploy contract using hardhat by forking mainnet?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am an beginner in writing test cases, i want to fork mainnet to use uniswap routor contract instance in my contract.

i am getting an error will running this code :

```
 1) Splitter
       Deploy and update Tokens:
     Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value="[object Object]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)
```

here is the code :

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Splitter", function () {
  // it("Should return the new greeting once it's changed", async function () {
  //   const Greeter = await ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
  //   const greeter = await Greeter.deploy("Hello, world!");
  //   await greeter.deployed();

  //   expect(await greeter.greet()).to.equal("Hello, world!");

  //   const setGreetingTx = await greeter.setGreeting("Hola, mundo!");

  //   // wait until the transaction is mined
  //   await setGreetingTx.wait();

  //   expect(await greeter.greet()).to.equal("Hola, mundo!");
  // });

  
  it("Deploy and update Tokens", async function (){
    // const DAI_Address = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;
     const ROUTER_Address = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D";
     console.log("hl")
     const WETH_Address = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";
     console.log("2");
     const Router = await ethers.getContractAt('IUniswapV2Router02',ROUTER_Address);
     console.log("3");
     const WETH = await ethers.getContractAt('IWETH',WETH_Address);
     console.log("4");

    const Splitter_Address = await ethers.getContractFactory("SwapSplitter");
    const Splitter = await Splitter_Address.deploy(Router, WETH);
    await Splitter.deployed();

    // expect(await Splitter.UniswapV2Router02()).to.equal(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
    // expect(await Splitter.WETH9()).to.equal(0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2);

    // const updateTokens = await splitter.UpdateTokens(DAI_Address, DAI_Address, DAI_Address);
    // await updateTokens.wait();

    // expect(await Splitter.tokenUSD()).to.equal(DAI_Address);
  })

  // Construction to get any contract as an object by its interface and address in blockchain
  // It is necessary to note that you must add an interface to your project
  // const WETH = await ethers.getContractAt('IWETH', wethAddress);
  // const UniswapV2Router02 = await ethers.getContractAt('IUniswapV2Router02', routerAddress);
});
```

Comment: What are you network configurations in the hardhat.config? (see https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/guides/mainnet-forking#forking-from-mainnet)

Comment: here is my network config `networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: "https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/id",
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: i am using the key just showing you that i have

Comment: Try deploying the Splitter with `const Splitter = await Splitter_Address.deploy(Router, WETH.address);` or `const Splitter = await Splitter_Address.deploy(Router, WETH_Address);`

Comment: Actually i am getting error here 
`const Router = await ethers.getContractAt('IUniswapV2Router02',ROUTER_Address);`

Comment: Do you have the code for 'IUniswapV2Router02' in your directory? (see: https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers for reference)

Comment: no, do we have to ??

Comment: Yes. Or the ABI (read the docs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we are using `.getContractAt` you must need interface or contract in you contract directory, just put the name of interface or contract in qoutes.

```
const Router = await ethers.getContractAt('IUniswapV2Router02',ROUTER_Address);
```

we need an interface of of `IUniswapV2Router02` in directory as said by @ikijong to deploy instance of that contract.well you must fork mainnet first by initializing it in `hardhat.config.js`

```
networks: {     
   hardhat: {       
      forking: {         
         url: "https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/id",  // you must change this id    
      }     
   }   
}
```

here you have to change id with you given id in **alchemy**. Then you can check it by calling functions of the contract.

And said by @Kuly14 you have give address of the contract not the full contract.

```
const Splitter = await Splitter_Address.deploy(Router.address, WETH.address);
```

for any more question about it you can comment.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
const Splitter = await Splitter_Address.deploy(Router, WETH);
```

You are trying to pass the whole contract as argument while it just needs the address. So modify it like this:

```
const Splitter = await Splitter_Address.deploy(Router.address, WETH.address);
```

Also, you don't really need to get the router contract since you can interact with it in your contract. Just pass it the address.

Comment: Actually i am getting error from this line :
`const Router = await ethers.getContractAt('IUniswapV2Router02',ROUTER_Address);`

Comment: can you help with getting an instance of an deployed contract on mainnet